# O que fazer quando obtiver respostas sobre a questão, e também conseguir formular uma resposta própria, seria interessante colocar ou não?

Tags: debate, respostas

O assunto que desejo debater é bem específico, forneço o link para o post - [Qual é a maneira correta para automatizar função a aplicar um mesmo efeito, para todas tag correspondente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/182904)

Lá foi mais uma de minhas resposta onde, deixei claro e objetiva. E mesmo fazendo com dedicação e esforço pessoal, vejo que sempre que tento contribuir de minha parte levo negativo.

Sempre que possível, tento contribuir colocando-a disposição uma resposta alternativa para que sirva de referência para construir novos conhecimentos no âmbito da linguagem e da programação, adotando a metodologia *Cross-Browser*.

E só faço essa prática após receber respostas de outros colegas, conservando a ética sobre boas prática não desvalorizando o esforço de ninguém em que me ajudou com sua opinião, sugestão e resposta.

Comment: Relacionada: [Respondi minha própria pergunta, fiz algo errado?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37/7210)

Comment: @JorgeB. O engraçado fica pela parte de que, não procuro levar mérito de doutorado em programação, mas quando a gente obtêm mais de uma resposta e torna-se de dificil escolha ai colocamos a nossa reposta, alguém/algum mau usuário intencionado olha de olho torto e seta o dedo "downVote", como se diz - vamos dar um negativo pra ele né. Acesse - [Usuário votou negativo na minha resposta para subir a própria resposta. O que a moderação pode fazer?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5590)

Comment: Acredito que o motivo dos downvotes seja por que sua resposta está apresentando erro no console.

Comment: @FelipePaetzold Vlw pela dica estava suspeitando que estivesse ocorrendo erros em diferentes versões de variados tipo de navegadores mais familiares. Isso é uma pena, pois no **firefox 11** funfa que é uma beleza, ja notei que algumas repostas que recebo também ocorre o mesmo. Vou ter que sempre fazer um _Snippet_ e um link externo para alguma plataforma on-line. Agradeço pelo feedback! :D

Comment: @DiegoHenrique deixe explicito na resposta que funciona normalmente no firefox ^^

Comment: @DiegoHenrique de qualquer forma alguém poderia dar esse feedback direto na resposta. Mas muita gente não explica o motivo do downvote

Comment: @FelipePaetzold Verdade, verdadeira. Em todo caso vou editar colocando o navegador web e a versão no qual funcionou perfeitamente. E claro adicionar um link para demonstração em funcionamento

Comment: @DiegoHenrique eu nem disse nada que não sei analisar o que você fez, só coloquei a pergunta relacionada para ficarem vinculadas.

Comment: @DiegoHenrique, cheguei atrasado na conversa (e deixo claro que não fui um dos downvoters), só te passando um *feedback* honesto sobre os possíveis motivos dos *downvotes*, além da questão do cross-browser  posso mencionar a formatação do código que está estranha e o fato da resposta ser uma variação bem próxima da resposta anterior (apenas agrupando os efeitos em um objeto comum). Não acho que o fato de você ter respondido sua própria pergunta tenha sido o problema, seria muito bom se todo mundo fizesse isso.

Comment: Por sinal, no SOen apenas linkar algo da W3Schools te trazia downvotes (veja [essa minha resposta de 2011 com um *downvote* e a "explicação"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5820702/664577)). *Downvotes* acontecem por motivos engraçados, não esquente com eles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Claro que é interessante, é sempre bom ter uma variedade de soluções para um problema, se a sua resposta foi a melhor solução, pode assinalá-la como correta sem medo, o site permite isso.

Quanto mais respostas (de qualidade) em uma questão melhor.

Comment: Claro que concordo com seu ponto-de-vista. No entanto o engraçado e deselegante é que a resposta que me deram em JQuery o usuário tinha no mínimo de pontuação em reputação, e desqualificaram o novato deixando peixe grande por dentro do post. A reposta do peixe pequeno era muitoooo boa, removeram. Julgo desigual!

Comment: @DiegoHenrique só tem 2 respostas deletadas nesta sua pergunta, e uma foi o próprio autor que excluiu.

Comment: @DiegoHenrique não me parece que ninguém tivesse apagado uma reposta válida.

Comment: @JorgeB. Acho que nosso colega **diegofm** ja localizou e esclareceu. No demais a resposta funcionava, só que é uma pena ele ter removido poderia ajudar alguém que prefira tabalhar com JQuery.

Comment: @diegofm Então deve-ser o próprio autor mesmo visto que ele mesmo disse se poderia ser JQuery. Aviso - uma foi eu que pedi para remover pois fui eu que postei a reposta duplicada sem querer falha nossa! rsrs.

Answer (score 6):

Diego, veja: [Usuários que mais respondem a própria pergunta](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/626157/usuarios-que-mais-respondem-a-propria-pergunta), tomei a liberdade de montar essa query*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se formos fazer uma analise criteriosa dos dados apresentados, do top 10 usuários que mais respondem a própria pergunta, você é um dos mais novos, e um dos que possui a pior media em respostas dadas...

Acredito que o gargalo não esteja nas suas perguntas (apesar de já ter te alertado sobre isso, acredito que existe muita coisa que deveria melhorar nas suas perguntas, principalmente na montagem dela, quando vai se explicar você acaba colocando muita informação desnecessária e acaba fugindo muito do contexto, alem de deixar confusa), elas possuem ate uma media considerável de pontuação, mas sim nas suas respostas, que possuem os mesmos problemas que suas perguntas.

Agora vou dar minha analise pessoal, não vejo problema nenhum em responder a própria pergunta, e não tem, a comunidade incentiva fortemente isso!

Mas geralmente quem vem pra rede com uma pergunta pronta, tem intenções reais de obter uma resposta correta pra sua duvida, e não tem uma resposta pronta pra mesma, realmente são duvidas.

Veja nesse meu exemplo: [Trabalhando com drag drop redips](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71711/trabalhando-com-drag-drop-redips).

Eu obtive uma resposta, aceitei a resposta como a correta e dei a gratificação de recompensa que ofereci na pergunta, como eu fiz uma pergunta muito fechada, onde seria difícil eu obter a resposta aqui na rede, fiz a mesma pergunta no SOen, e obtive uma resposta (do próprio autos do plugin!) que acabou me ajudando mais do que essa resposta que eu aceitei, e decidi compartilhar a resposta aqui na rede, pra ficar como alternativa do que eu realmente usei.

Agora pense assim, pelo menos eu sou assim, quando surge uma nova pergunta e eu me proponho a responder, acredito que o usuário que fez a pergunta não tenha uma resposta pronta, e eu me dedico a resposta, como aconteceu nessa aqui: [Dúvida com data e hora no sql server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180542/d%C3%BAvida-com-data-e-hora-no-sql-server/180602#180602) eu não entendia muito de `SQL Server` e me dediquei pra ir atras do assunto e dar uma resposta que ajudasse o autor da pergunta, levei umas 5 horas pra conseguir responder "corretamente".

Outro exemplo que ocorreu comigo recentemente, nessa pergunta: [Usando editor WYSIWYG com angular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/182221/usando-editor-wysiwg-com-angular), eu comecei a desenvolver esse modulo, fiquei com essa duvida e postei a pergunta, dentro da própria pergunta fui corrigindo o código e consegui solucionar a duvida, agora mesmo tendo chegado a uma solução, não sei se foi a mais eficiente, então mesmo com uma resposta aceita (a minha) eu ofereci uma recompensa de +100 ponto pra quem soubesse uma melhor alternativa, porque senti que esta pergunta não recebeu atenção suficiente da comunidade.

Agora com você já me aconteceu 2 ou 3 vezes isso, você posta a pergunta, me proponho a ajudar, dou uma resposta e você vem depois dizendo que tem uma solução já pronta..... isso me desestimula enormemente, e eu me prometi depois dessa ultima que não vou mais me prestar a responder perguntas suas....

Bom, enfim....

Nem sempre as respostas que você da a sua própria pergunta estão corretas, algumas existem falhas de execução ou de sintaxe, ou mesmo de codificação, que podem acarretar nos -1 que recebe em algumas respostas suas.

Essa resposta fica meio como um conselho, não precisa parar com essa atitude, veja que o Guilherme, o Wallace e o Bigown tem uma alta taxa de perguntas respondidas por eles mesmos, mas compare as respostas deles, com as suas, eu acredito que você tenha que dar uma melhorada no conteúdo das suas perguntas, e no conteúdo das suas respostas.

Deixo também um link para ver todas as perguntas que foram respondidas pelo próprio user [Todas perguntas respondidas por você mesmo](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/revision/626167/782125/todas-perguntas-respondidas-por-voce-mesmo), caso queira fazer uma comparação, é só jogar o id do usuário que ele puxa todas perguntas e respostas feitas pelo mesmo usuário.

*Lembrando que o data.stackexchange.com atualiza a cada segunda feira, portanto podem existir valores desatualizados.

Comment: Alterei a query para linkar o perfil do usuario: https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/626157/usuarios-que-mais-respondem-a-propria-pergunta

Comment: @diegofm alterei na resposta o link rs vlw

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Confesso a você que gosto da sua participação! E aprovo muito isso que vêm fazendo no decorrer da rede SOP, sempre melhorando e dando opinião, sugestão e resposta e melhormente no contexto estabelecendo uma meta de conteúdo irrelevante.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Acho que cada explicação em seu contexto basei-se na mente do seu original autor. Então não o faço com maldade mas precisamente o quê tenho em mente seja com deficiência na Pergunta, e assim mesmo a ponho em evidência, cada qual coloca conforme compreende. Tenho certeza que ao passar dos anos melhoro sim. Apenas estou começando .. seja com todos ou sozinho irei prossegui adiante ...

Comment: @DiegoHenrique juro que não entendi a sua linha de raciocínio... e talvez seja esse o maior problema de suas perguntas e respostas....